# Resizing Plots VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am having issues with resizing images in VBA. I have tried a bunch of methods and here is the code that I am using:

```
    Sub Macro17()
    '
    ' Macro17 Macro
    '
    '
    Call Macro1
    Call Macro2
    End Sub

    Sub Macro1()
    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A77:N79").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A58:N58,A77:N79")


     With ActiveChart
     'chart name
    .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
    .ChartTitle.Text = " Plot 1"
     'X axis name
    '.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    '.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "X-Axis"
     'y-axis name
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "y - label"
End With
    ActiveChart.Parent.Cut
    Sheets("Plots").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Plots").Range("B2:B5")
    With ActiveChart.Parent
    .Height = 369
    .Width = 520
  End With

End Sub

Sub Macro2()
Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A83:N85").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A58:N58,A83:N85")


     With ActiveChart
     'chart name
    .SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
    .ChartTitle.Text = " Plot Two"
     'X axis name
    '.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    '.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "X-Axis"
     'y-axis name
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "y - label"
End With
    ActiveChart.Parent.Cut
    Sheets("Plots").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Plots").Range("B30:B35")
    With ActiveChart.Parent
    .Height = 369
    .Width = 520
  End With
  ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelPosition = xlTickLabelPositionLow

End Sub
```

So I use Macro17, to call both Macro1 and Macro2, and then plot the appropriate data, my issue is that when I call Macro17, only the first plot is made bigger. When I run through both macros with the debugger using F8 (in windows) I have no issues and the code runs as expeceted, but this is extremely in efficient. It probably has to do with how `ActiveChart.Parent` is used. Thank you for all your help it is much appreciated.

Comment: At a quick look, it could have something to do with your using `.Select`. I highly suggest reading through [how to avoid using `.Select`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros), which can relieve some issues in VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is created when `ActiveChart` is called again, the reason for this issue is that it isn't sure which chart is active. The solution is to use `ActiveChart.Parent.Name = "Test"` and then before `ActiveChart` is called again you have to use: `ActiveSheet.Shapes("Test").Select`. The key here is that when using `ActiveSheets.Shapes()` duplicates won't be handled well.

Comment: Once you have the chart created you should be able to use `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects()` to reference the chart instead of `ActiveSheet.Shapes()`

Comment: @JerryT using ChartObjects() didn't work for me, I'm not exactly sure why.

Comment: `    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Test")
        .Height = 369
        .Width = 520
    End With`